# Recommended scope for grails plugins

Tags: grails

I've got a list of grails plugings in my 1.3.7 app.
I'm converting it to 2.1.0 and doing a cleanup.

In my application.properties I have the following:

```
plugins.build-test-data=2.0.3
plugins.fixtures=1.1
plugins.hibernate=2.1.0
plugins.pretty-time=0.3
plugins.mail=1.0
plugins.quartz=0.4.2
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.7.3
plugins.tomcat=2.1.0
```

I'm moving them all to my BuildConfig.groovy instead.

I'm curious as to what is the most appropriate scope for each plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My usual rule of thumb is

- `build` scope for plugins that are part of the build process but shouldn't go into the WAR for production deployment
- `test` scope for things that should be available to tests but not to application code
- `runtime` scope for plugins (or JAR dependencies) that you need for the app to run but which you don't want to tightly couple your app to (you can't `import` a class from a `runtime` dependency into one of your app's own classes, for example)
- `compile` scope for everything else

If in doubt, `compile` will definitely work, as plugins in `application.properties` are treated as if they were declared in `compile` scope.

So `tomcat` definitely wants `build` scope, `spring-security-core` definitely wants `compile`, I guess `fixtures` and `build-test-data` should be `test`, the others `compile` or `runtime` depending on whether you need to `import` any of their classes directly.